# Extracting Name from a plain text in java

Tags: java, parsing, nlp

is there any way to parse name (firstname and lastName s ) from a plain text.Names can be from any country. For now i am building a database of possible names i can get. Is there any other good methods?

Comment: you try to check if the word is in a dictionary (avaible online) or maybe if have capital letter or if there are some pre-name like Mr, Mrs and Miss or MD., Ing. etc.

Comment: this one have to be generic..can't depend on the structure of the text

Comment: Do you know for certain whether all of the names are from countries that use "first name followed by last name" order?

Comment: i am trying to parse names from a resume..so i cant be sure that whether it will be at top part or middle or at the end,it can be anywhere ..this text file contains lot of other data as well. so i have to separate name from everything else

Comment: are you writing the file? maybe you can add something to find the correct place?

Comment: Check Apache OpenNLP. There's a simple example there :  http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/opennlp-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general NLP this problem is a subset of the [NER (Named Entity Recognition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) problem. It can be approached in at least two ways:

- rule based system - so you build simple rules, like the dictinary check-up, regexps for some Mr., Phd. prefixes etc. and base your extraction on those
- machine learning based systems - you characterize each word token with some lexical and statistical properties and train some classifier (like for example [HMM](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/acl2002/MAIN/pdfs/Main036.pdf) or [CRF](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml)) to detect whether the particular word (token) is a first or last name.